# Why my Angular directive input is not been posted?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm trying create a directive to reuse in a form. But when I submit, the input (directive) is not there.

This is my tag:

```
<core-input type="text" icon="person" name="name" placeholder="Name" ng-model="mymodel.name"></core-input>
```

This is my directive js code:

```
angular.module('StarterApp').directive('coreInput', function($compile) {
    return {
        restrict: 'AE',
        require: '?ngModel',
        scope: true,
        link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
            if (!ngModel) return;
            scope.onChange = function() {
                ngModel.$setViewValue(scope.value);
            };
            ngModel.$render = function() {
                scope.opts = attrs;
                scope.value = ngModel.$modelValue;
                $compile(element.contents())(scope);
            };
        },
        templateUrl: function(elem, attr) {
            return './app/views/directives/form/' + attr.type + '.html';
        }
    };
});
```

And this is what I want reuse:

```
<md-input-container class="md-icon-float md-block" flex-gt-sm md-no-float>
    <md-icon class="material-icons">
        <i class="material-icons">{{ opts.icon }}</i>
    </md-icon>
    <input type="text" name="{{ opts.name }}" placeholder="{{ opts.placeholder }}" ng-model="$parent.ngModel">
</md-input-container>
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

The angular documentation states that $setViewValue don't call the $render method on ngModel. So this have to be called manually. As the html of the element has changed shiould be possible to retrieve the original template from the angular service $templateCache

```
var urlPrefix = './app/views/directives/form/';
var templateExtension = '.html';
angular.module('StarterApp').directive('coreInput',['$compile', '$templateCache' function($compile, $templateCache) {
    return {
        restrict: 'AE',
        require: '?ngModel',
        scope: true,
        link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
            if (!ngModel) return;
            scope.onChange = function() {
                ngModel.$setViewValue(scope.value);
                ngMode.$render();
            };
            ngModel.$render = function() {
                var template = $templateCache.get(urlPrefix + attrs.type + templateExtension);
                element.html(template);
                $compile(element.contents())(scope);
            };
        },
        templateUrl: function(elem, attr) {
            return urlPrefix + attr.type + templateExtension;
        }
    };
}]);
```

Comment: Sorry for been messy. No need to return anything. Just call the $render. In the documentation it is written that the $setViewValue don't call the $render function.

Comment: Do I have to change something at the html? Because it continue not working and the others variables ({{ opts... }}) stop work too

Comment: It is posible that the html has change and it doesn't have the angular expresions `{{...}}`. Try to update the model on the render function instead of recompiling the whole template. If it doesn't work you'll need to retrieve the template with $templateCache, to avoid other request.

Comment: I've add `scope.opts = attrs` and the variables start to work. But nothing to post the field. Before start use directive I was using `ng-include="'template.html'"` but I was having the same problem, the field wasn't been sent